# How to solve the recurrence T(n)=T(n-1) + ... T(1) +1?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I need to find the complexity of an algorithm that involves the recurrence:

`T(n) = T(n-1) + ... + T(1) + 1`

`T(n)` is the time it takes to solve a problem of size `n`.

The master method doesn't apply here and I can't make a guess to use the substitution method (I don't want to use the substitution method anyway).
I'm left with recursion tree method.

Since the number of children of each node isn't a constant, I'm finding it hard to keep track of how much each node contributes. What is the underlying pattern?

I understand that I have to find the number of nodes in a tree in which each node (`k`) has for its children all nodes numbered from 1 to `k-1`.

Is it also possible to find the exact time `T(n)` given that formula?

Comment: Though it doesn't currently use DP, I think the problem fits in that category.

Comment: "I can't make a guess to use the substitution method." I take it you haven't made a table of the small `T(n)`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, what table are you referring to? Since it doesn't use DP, there isn't a table if I'm right. Isn't it a tree here?
Also, I don't want to use the substitution method honestly.

Comment: A table of small `T(n)`: `T(1)`, `T(2)`, `T(3)`, ....  That should give a pretty good pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `T(n-1) = T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + 1`

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + 1
     = T(n-1) + T(n-1)
     = 2*T(n-1)
```

and `T(1) = 1` => `T(n) = 2^(n-1)`